# Touch screen drivers

Tags: linux, gentoo, touch-screen, touch

I have an Android tablet which is using Atom CPU, so I want to get Linux onto it.

I used Gentoo(4.2.4 kernel), everything is fine except for the touch screen. On Android I can see the following modules related to the touch screen:

```
gt9xx_ts
atmel_mxt_ts
```

Googling tells me that they're Goodix's and Atmel mXT's. Enabling them in kernel, and even trying this [Goodix touch screen driver on GitHub](https://github.com/hadess/gt9xx), I still can't get an event for the touch screen in `/dev/input`(in Linux there are `{0..4}`, in android there are `{0..6}`, and after cat'ing them, event5 is the one that responds to touches).

My kernel config is this: [Kernel config](https://dpaste.de/RegH).

---

Now I wasn't to know about these:

1. What generic kernel options does a touch screen need besides the ones I have enabled?
2. If I got everything right, will I get a node for it in `/dev` and `/sys`?

Comment: ... I wish I could help. have you achieved something? please post :)